# How to set blur background of text in html

Tags: html, .net

I have written code in html to make blur background of image but it sets whole text plus image background to blur. How to solve this?

```
<div  style="background-image: url('Images/aaboutus.jpg'); -webkit-filter: blur(2px); height: 700px; background-repeat: no-repeat; ">

     <table border="0"  align="center" frame="box"  style="height: 400px;">

<tr>
<td>
<p>Hello World</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style="height: 700px;">
    <img src="Images/aaboutus.jpg" style="-webkit-filter: blur(2px);" />
    <table border="0" align="center" frame="box" style="height: 400px;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```